# Normal Approximation of Sums

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

> Let $X$ be a random variable with
>
> $P(X=-1)=\frac{1}{4}$
>
> $P(X=0)=\frac{1}{4}$
>
> $P(X=1)=\frac{1}{2}$
>
> Let $S$ be the sum of 25 independent random variables with the same
>   distribution as $X$. Calculate **approximately** $P(S<0)$.

$X_i$, $1 \le i \le 25$, has the same distribution. Thus, over the long run, the distribution of $S$ is approximately normal so we can use normal approximation.

$P(S<0)$

$= P(\frac{S-E(S)}{σ} < \frac{0-E(S)}{σ})$

$= P(z < \frac{0-E(S)}{σ})$ where $z = \frac{S-E(S)}{σ}$

$= P(z < \frac{0-\frac{25}{4}}{\sqrt{Var(S)}})$

$= P(z < \frac{0-\frac{25}{4}}{\sqrt{\frac{275}{16}}})$

$= P(z < \frac{0-\frac{25}{4}}{\sqrt{\frac{275}{16}}})$

$= P(z < -1.507556723)$

$=\Phi(-1.507556723)$

$=1 - \Phi(1.507556723)$

$=1 - 0.9345$

$=0.0655$

**Textbook Answer:**

> 0.05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your answer differs from the textbook is because you did not employ continuity correction for the normal approximation.  Specifically, $$\Pr[S < 0] \approx \Pr\left[\frac{S - \operatorname{E}[S]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[S]}} < \frac{\color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}} - \frac{25}{4}}{\sqrt{\frac{275}{16}}}\right].$$  The use of $-1/2$ instead of $0$ arises because the exact distribution is discrete, hence $\Pr[S = 0]$ has a nonzero probability; under the normal approximation, using $0$ would in a sense include half of this probability mass in your answer.

Comment: So the only case where we don't use continuity correction is when the original distribution is indeed normal?

Comment: No.  As I alluded to in my answer, continuity correction is a consideration whenever there is a difference between something like $\Pr[X < x]$ versus $\Pr[X \le x]$.  Thus, when the exact distribution is discrete, continuity correction should be used.  But if the exact distribution is continuous (e.g., sums of Gamma variables), no continuity correction is required.

Comment: Another question, if we apply the continuity correction, wouldn't the inequality change? From $P(S \lt 0)$ to $P(S \le -\frac{1}{2})$?

Comment: No.  $S$ is a discrete variable, but you are approximating it with a continuous one, say $Y$.  So what you are really trying to say is $$\Pr[S < 0] \approx \Pr[Y \le -1/2]$$ where $Y$ is a normal random variable with mean $\mu = \operatorname{E}[S]$ and variance $\sigma^2 = \operatorname{Var}[S]$.  Then we standardize $Y$ to obtain a $z$-score that we can look up in a table.